# How to create 'widescreen' and 'computer' class in same grid using Semantic UI

Tags: grid, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, multiscreen

How to create more than one screen size in the same grid like below

```
<Grid.Column width={1} only='widescreen' width={2} only='computer' verticalAlign='middle' centered>
    Content here
</Grid.Column>
```

This is not working. It's always taking the last given style (`width={2} only='computer'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid.Column widescreen={1} computer={2}>
    Content here
</Grid.Column>
```

This is worked! Thanks